# Changes on a sheet made by AppSheet don't occur

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-appsheet

hope you can help me. I have made a simple App (with AppSheet) that use a Google Sheet file. The goal is managing different tasks I'll assign to my co-workers.
In my app I see all the tasks listed in a table, I can open each row, see the task as a card and with an action button open the form to edit the person who is working on that task and the day of assignment.
However, in the Google Sheet data source I need a sheet that records every edit that has be done through AppSheet.

I tried using the onEdit installable trigger on the sheet and a script (written in AppsScripts) that records every edit, but unfortunately it doesn't work. The trigger is never called by the changes that AppSheet made. Have I done something wrong? Is there another way to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are having a "classic" misunderstanding about how the onEdit simple trigger works. Long story short, it only works for edits done manually using the Google Sheets user interface. Instead of using the onEdit simple trigger you might use the on change installable trigger but you should be aware that the event object is very different.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/39483929/1595451, https://stackoverflow.com/q/75181005/1595451

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is achievable in AppSheet alone, no need to employ App Script since it may not directly capture the changes made on your spreadsheet since it is not user initiated.

You need to have a ***last_edit*** (date/timestamp) column in your Google Sheet data source, then on AppSheet, set an expression (aka formula) in your column properties for it to be automatically populated with the current date and time whenever the form is opened.

You can refer to these resources for more information:

- [Tables: The Essentials](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10105821?hl=en&sjid=5224870128749234443-AP#configure-table)
- [Expressions: The Essentials](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10104642?hl=en&sjid=5224870128749234443-AP)

  - [Date and time expressions](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10107326?hl=en&ref_topic=10104376&sjid=5224870128749234443-AP)
- [Time Keeping | App templates](https://www.appsheet.com/templates?sjid=5224870128749234443-AP&q=time%20keeping)

  - [Timesheet Tracker](https://www.appsheet.com/templates/Employee-timesheet-log-with-historical-calendar?appGuidString=37224834-68d2-4e1f-9cbe-773ce9df8c1e)

Hope this helps.